# Translate API response data in angular or Laravel (before sending to frontend)

Tags: angular, laravel, localization, internationalization, translation

I have frontend in angular and backend in Laravel. There is one API by which I gets names of colors in array. I need to translate that depending on default language set. I have two json files en.json, de.json in frontend and backend.

Is there any way by which I can translate API response data in angular or in Laravel can I send translated data to frontend? Can we make use of json files in this translation like we use for static data?

I searched but unfortunate to find any solution to this.

Please help and guide.

Answer (score 0):

The way how and where to translate depends on your app specific.

Usually, the static data (which is limited and not changing often) is translated on the side of your js app, and the dynamic data, which can be extended or updating often, usually translated on backend side and returned already translated via API.

For example, if the total amount of possible colors is limited and you query 3rd party API directly from the frontend - it makes sense to use translations in your Angular app.

If 3rd party API is queried on Laravel side and then the results passed to your frontend app, new colors can be added often etc. - it makes sense to send already translated data to Angular.

Answer (score 0):

There is this library you can use in frontend for your translation https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

From there instead of returning ready to show values from your backend you can returns JSON keys to be used alongside the provided pipe in that library